# inproceedings booktitle does not appear

Tags: natbib, templates

I am using a latex template provided by a publisher's website (`wileyNJD-AMA`). The problem I am facing is that the conference's book title does not appear at all.  I am using the following referencing style

```
@inproceedings{son2015cloudsimsdn,
    title="CloudSimSDN: Modeling and simulation of software-defined cloud data centers",
    author="Son, Jungmin and Dastjerdi, Amir Vahid and Calheiros, Rodrigo N and Ji, Xiaohui and Yoon, Young and Buyya, Rajkumar",
    booktitle="Cluster, Cloud and Grid Computing",
    year="2015",
    pages="475--484",
    organization="IEEE"
}
```

Here what appears:

> Son Jungmin, Dastjerdi Amir Vahid, Calheiros Rodrigo N, Ji Xiaohui,
>   Yoon Young, Buyya Rajkumar. Cloudsimsdn: Modeling and simulation of
>   software-defined cloud data centers. In: :475–484IEEE; 2015.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you please post a link to the latex template, and edit your question to show a minimal document using that template that produces the problem with the bib item you show. You've tagged this as `biblatex`, but are you actually using `biblatex` to produce the bibliography?

Comment: A bit of Googling suggests that this Wiley class does not use `biblatex`, but `natbib`, so I have removed the tag. Please check if that is indeed correct and show us a short example document that we can run as well as a link to your journal template.

Comment: Here is the link of the sample I am using

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/1097024x/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm

Answer (score 4):

**Edit after comment:**

I found a bug in their `WileyNJD-AMA.bst` file:

In line 473 there is :

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "In: " }
    { "In: " 
      editor empty$
    'skip$
    { " " * format.editors * " " * booktitle emphasize * " " * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

You have to replace it by:

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "In: " }
    { "In: " 
      editor empty$
    { " " * booktitle emphasize * "" * }
    { " " * format.editors * " " * booktitle emphasize * "" * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Alternative could be to add an editor in your entry but still I think my way is more correct and have to be replace their code.

Their @inbook emtry has the same problem.

Please consider to report the "bug" in the page you found the template.

Then everything works fine.

**Old answer before see the template:**

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@inproceedings{son2015cloudsimsdn,
    title="CloudSimSDN: Modeling and simulation of software-defined cloud data centers",
    author="Son, Jungmin and Dastjerdi, Amir Vahid and Calheiros, Rodrigo N and Ji, Xiaohui and Yoon, Young and Buyya, Rajkumar",
    booktitle="Cluster, Cloud and Grid Computing",
    year="2015",
    pages="475--484",
    organization="IEEE"
}
\end{filecontents}

\title{Test}
\author{Konstantinos Leledakis}
\date{September 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

According to known things \cite{son2015cloudsimsdn}\ldots

\section{Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My advice is to use `natbib` package like in my code, since it offers many citation options and I think you have the more options on the style of your bibliography (like harvard -which I used here- and many others)

May be is not the way you are looking for, but you didn't added a MWE (I mean code like mine... for more see here: [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/120578)) and we could not easily help you. (This is why you had not a fast answer).

Comment: I followed your way but it is still not showing the book title. Here is the link of the sample I am using

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/1097024x/homepage/la_tex_class_file.htm

Comment: Sorry the error is possibly in the `.bst` file... Looking for it but sure you can ask them too.

Comment: Finally found and corrected the "bug"

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue. I solved it by replacing the word "booktitle" with the word "series". Now it is working well.

```
@inproceedings{son2015cloudsimsdn,
    title="CloudSimSDN: Modeling and simulation of software-defined cloud data centers",
    author="Son, Jungmin and Dastjerdi, Amir Vahid and Calheiros, Rodrigo N and Ji, Xiaohui and Yoon, Young and Buyya, Rajkumar",
    series="Cluster, Cloud and Grid Computing",
    year="2015",
    pages="475--484",
    organization="IEEE"
}
```

Here is what appears:

> Son J, Dastjerdi AV, Calheiros RN, Ji X, Yoon Y, Buyya R. CloudSimSDN:
> Modeling and simulation of software-defined cloud data centers. In:
> Cluster, Cloud and Grid Computing. IEEE. ; 2015: 475–484.

Answer (score 0):

To add the period after the booktitle content to separate it from the next field content,

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { "In: " }
    { "In: " 
      editor empty$
    { " " * booktitle emphasize * ". " * }
    { " " * format.editors * " " * booktitle emphasize * ". " * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same error. Please give the exact name of your bib file as mentioned in bst file.
Use the following code:
`\bibliographystyle{WileyNJD-AMA}`
`\bibliography{WileyNJD-AMA}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. While short answers are ok, it is usually preferable to post a complete solution in form of [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304).

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem
Fixed using this simplified version

FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ booktitle empty$
    { " In: " }
    { " In: " * booktitle * "" * }
  if$
}

bst seems stack based (will look more later)