# How to correctly list a cite of a piece of software regarding its license

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm not sure on how to list a piece of software in my bibliography. 
Seems like bibs are made in a time when licences didn't bother anybody yet. ;-)
What I by now do is this:

```
@misc{ref2,
    Author = {xceedsoftware},
    Title = {wpftoolkit},
    Note = {\url{https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit}},
    Version = {Ms-PL}
    },
```

But this does not really match what I need because it lists the licence as Version Ms-PL. 
Whats the correct way of handling licences in softwarepackages I have to reference?

MWE solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{FiraSans}

\begin{filecontents}{license.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{license}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[software]{license}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, defernumbers, datamodel=license]{biblatex}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{skipbibliography}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\addtocategory{skipbibliography}{\thefield{entrykey}}%
   \usedriver
     {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\appto{\bibsetup}{\emergencystretch=1em}

\NewBibliographyString{license}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{license = {license},}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{license = {Lizenz},}

\DeclareFieldFormat{license}{\bibstring{license}\addcolon\space#1}
\renewbibmacro{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{license}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{wpf,
  author  = {{Xceed}},
  title   = {Extended WPF Toolkit},
  url     = {https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit},
  license = {Ms-PL},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,wpf}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you are using biblatex (according to your tags) you could have a try and use `addendum` (its like a second `note` field). Whether it is displayed or not depends on your bibliography style.

Comment: Do you really use `biblatex`? What style do you use? Can you show us a minimal example document that shows this entry in action, please? (If you really use `biblatex` don't use the `note` field to display the URL, use the dedicated `url` field)

Comment: Im cirrently experimenting with different styles so share me yours and i will likely adopt... also if you paste me a sample of one of your cites with url field i would apreciate.

Comment: Use code like this and make it an example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/451178/120578

Comment: i added a MWE and wold apreciate a help in changeing the full Bib to normal text nothing bold and all with the default Font.

Comment: The MWE as posted works brilliantly for me and produces https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OkgW.png. (1) Does that not work for you? (2) What output do you get instead? Please show a screenshot of the result. (3) Do you get any errors or warnings in the `.log` or `.blg` file after the LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX compilation cycle? (4) What version of `biblatex` and Biber are you running?

Comment: ah, you are right. add this: \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
then its bold as i wrote...

Comment: Well, you need something like `\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{license = {Lizenz},}` if you want a German translation as well.

Comment: Ideally you would not post solutions in the question as that can confuse and bypasses the Q&A scheme. I'll be happy to add the line to my MWE below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is tagged with `biblatex`, so I strongly suggest you use the dedicated `url` field instead of `note`.

I know of no style that has an explicit `license` field, so you can either use a different generic field (`note` works for almost all styles, `biblatex` or BibTeX alike; or `addendum` or `titleaddon` for `biblatex`)

```
@software{wpf,
  author  = {{Xceed}},
  title   = {Extended WPF Toolkit},
  url     = {https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit},
  note    = {License: Ms-PL}
}
```

Or you can use `biblatex`'s dynamic data model to add a `license` field (see [Add field "tome" to biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864)), in that case you also need to find a way to inject the `license` field into a suitable place in the bibliography (in the example below we patch into `addendum+pubstate` because that seemed a suitable place and because it is fairly simple to do so for `@software` entries, other places would have been more code-intensive).

The solution works with bibstrings to print "license", so you need to define the string for every language you intend to use, the MWE shows this for English and German.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{license.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{license}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[software]{license}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber, datamodel=license]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{license}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  license = {license},
}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  license = {Lizenz},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{license}{\bibstring{license}\addcolon\space#1}
\renewbibmacro{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \printfield{license}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@software{wpf,
  author  = {{Xceed}},
  title   = {Extended WPF Toolkit},
  url     = {https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit},
  license = {Ms-PL},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,wpf}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: *Journal of Computational Chemistry* 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.//Xceed (n.d.). *Extended WPF Toolkit.* url: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit. License: Ms-PL.]

Comment: oh. @software was the thing i was searching for. Does there exist a list of such options and its entities like 'licence'?

Comment: @novski The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) has a full list of all supported entry types and fields (§2).

Comment: thanks @moewe i was supprized to read that software is untreated by the styles. Maybe thats why "licence" is writen bold in this MWE? how can i make it normal?

Comment: i added a MWE and wold apreciate a help in changeing the full Bib to normal text nothing bold and all with the default Font.

Comment: @novski I don't see "license", or "licence" for that matter, printed in bold in the MWE. What exactly do you mean?